# Bootstrap image gallery always opens at top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [Bootstrap image gallery by Blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/). I've placed its container at the bottom of my Index.cshtml page:

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
```

Here's an example anchor tag that links to the gallery:

```
<a href="~/images/press/french/BABYBOOK-Couv-P-Ete-2014.png" 
  target="_blank" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery">
  <img src="~/images/press/french/thumbs/BABYBOOK-Couv-P-Ete-2014.jpg" 
    class="img-responsive magazine" />
</a>
```

When you click to open the gallery, it opens at the top of the page. I think these CSS rules control its position:

```
.blueimp-gallery {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  direction: ltr;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

.blueimp-gallery, .blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide>.slide-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

The `position:fixed` and `top:0`, `right:0`, `bottom:0`, `left:0` have something to do with the gallery always opening at the top of the page.

Is there a way to have the gallery open right where the user is on the page, so when they close the gallery, it returns them to their original location? Or is there a way to know where the user was on the page and return him/her to that spot after the gallery is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these solutions are like workarounds, I had the same issue with blueimp-gallery and finally I realized that it was happening because the library hides the page scroll bar by default, and when you open it goes straight to the top.

So in the options set `hidePageScrollbars:false`

when you initilialize the library:

```
blueimp.Gallery(links,{hidePageScrollbars:false});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to replicate your specific problem but you could try something of this nature:

```
.blueimp-gallery{
position:fixed;
top:50%; 
left:50%;
width:80%;  /* adjust as per your needs */
height:80%;   /* adjust as per your needs */
margin-left:-40%;   /* negative half of width above */
margin-top:-40%;   /* negative half of height above */
}
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks, @Kinburn101, for your code, but the gallery still jumps to top of page. Now it shows only bottom half of the gallery though; the rest is outside of view at the top of the page.

Comment: I must be missing something that is not apparent in the code you have posted. Without seeing a working model to show the initial properties assigned to `.blueimp-gallery` by various sources it will be hard to identify where the conflict is.

Comment: Thanks, @Kinburn101, for the quick reply. You can go here for a working example: http://mj-dev.azurewebsites.net/. Click on the "Our Story" menu item, then choose the "Press" tab, then scroll toward the bottom to the "Baby Mag" item and click either of its images.

Comment: I'm not the strongest with javascript and jquery but within the `blueimp-gallery.js` file you may want to investigate this `// The event object for which the default action will be canceled // on Gallery initialization (e.g. the click event to open the Gallery): event: undefined,` You should be looking for a method to prevent the default action of clicking the anchor tag which opens the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a different Bootstrap gallery and experienced the same issue: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/. It must be something to do with other logic on the page. Switched back to the Blueimp Gallery, and used this kludge that will make the user believe they stayed at the same location on the page.

Add a DIV to the page:

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Style it so it will obscure the entire page when it's displayed:

```
#overlay {
    background-color:#000; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    right:0; 
    left:0; 
    z-index: 999999; 
    display:none;
}
```

Use the Blueimp API via jQuery to show/hide this div. Also, `onopen` of the gallery (fired before the gallery sends the user to the top of the page), detect the user's location (`scrollTop`). Then use the `onclose`, fired before the gallery closes, to scroll to that location on the page. I had to use the `animate()` function; the regular `scrollTop` didn't work for some reason.

This all goes into the `$(window).load()` function:

```
var scrollPosition; 
$('#blueimp-gallery')
    .on('open', function (event) {
        // Gallery open event handler
        $('#overlay').show();
        scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    })
    .on('opened', function (event) {
        // Gallery opened event handler
    })
    .on('slide', function (event, index, slide) {
        // Gallery slide event handler
    })
    .on('slideend', function (event, index, slide) {
        // Gallery slideend event handler
    })
    .on('slidecomplete', function (event, index, slide) {
        // Gallery slidecomplete event handler
    })
    .on('close', function (event) {
        // Gallery close event handler

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollPosition
        }, 600, function () {
            $('#overlay').hide();
        });
        //$('html').scrollTop(scrollPosition);
    })
    .on('closed', function (event) {
        // Gallery closed event handler
    });
```

Hope this helps others.